# Jquery issue on changing the url or loading the url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

With the below script I was trying to load the output of the variable "url" in the browser on clicking the anchor tag, while executing it shows the expected result path in the alert box but it loads the path mentioned in the anchor tag. I want to load the output path in the browser's same tab. please help me to solve this.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        $("a").on('click', function(){
            var reqURL = window.location.href;
            var hrefVal = $(this).attr('href');
            var url;        
            if(hrefVal.indexOf("http")== -1){
                if(reqURL.indexOf("/ca-en") != -1){
                    url="http://www.mywebsite.com/site2"+hrefVal;
                }else if(reqURL.indexOf("/ca-fr")> -1){
                    url="http://www.mywebsite.com/site3"+hrefVal;
                }else{
                    url="http://www.mywebsite.com"+hrefVal;     
                }
                alert(url);
                window.open(url,"_self");
            }       
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <ul>
    <li>
        <a class="category" href="/home.html">home<span class="icon plus"></span></a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="/home/abc.html">abc</a></li>
            <li><a href="/home/xyz.html">xyz</a></li>
            <li><a href="/home/tam.html">tam</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So you want to see the content of the url on the browser page, and want to see the url on the address bar. This is exactly what a simple `<a href=...>` does.

Comment: You seem very confused about the <a> element. Maybe some reading is necessary?

Comment: Check `window.location`.

Comment: @viktor need to see or update the url only to the address bar

Comment: @pugazh showing same result

Comment: If you just want to change the URL. Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page

Comment: @Viktor simply, now in address bar i am seeing file:///C:/home.html but i want to see http://www.mywebsite.com/home.html

Comment: @thamizhinian check my answer. The issue is about default behavior of anchor tag.

Comment: also if i am adding window.open(url); it loads the page in the another window so i added window.open(url,"_self"); facing the same issue mentioned in the top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default behaviour of the anchor tag has to be stopped prior to executing your custom behaviour logic. your code can be written as follows:

```
<script>
$(function(){   
    $("a").on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var reqURL = window.location.href;
        var hrefVal = $(this).attr('href');
        var url;        
        if(hrefVal.indexOf("http")== -1){
            if(reqURL.indexOf("/ca-en") != -1){
                url="http://www.mywebsite.com/site2"+hrefVal;
            }else if(reqURL.indexOf("/ca-fr")> -1){
                url="http://www.mywebsite.com/site3"+hrefVal;
            }else{
                url="http://www.mywebsite.com"+hrefVal;     
            }
            alert(url);
            window.open(url,"_self");
        }       
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: it works awesome, this what i expected, thank you so much

Comment: @thamizhinian I posted the same 4 minutes before this ans with fiddler example! have you seen or not?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `onclick` function on `anchor tag`. otherwise it will always redirect to `href` path of `anchor tag` before the javascrip `window.open` load.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    function redirect(parameter){
            var reqURL = window.location.href;
            var hrefVal = parameter;
            var url;        
            if(hrefVal.indexOf("http")== -1){
                if(reqURL.indexOf("/ca-en") != -1){
                    url="http://www.mywebsite.com/site2"+hrefVal;
                }else if(reqURL.indexOf("/ca-fr")> -1){
                    url="http://www.mywebsite.com/site3"+hrefVal;
                }else{
                    url="http://www.mywebsite.com"+hrefVal;     
                }
                alert(url);
                window.open(url,"_self");

            }
    }

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <ul>
    <li>
        <a class="category" href="/home.html">home<span class="icon plus"></span></a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#" onclick="redirect('/home/abc.html')">abc</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="redirect('/home/xyz.html')">xyz</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="redirect('/home/tam.html')">tam</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- <li><a href="/home/abc.html">abc</a></li>

+ <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-url="/home/abc.html">abc</a></li>


- var hrefVal = $(this).attr('href');

+ var hrefVal = $(this).data('url');
```

Very simple..

Answer (score 0):

The issue is about when you are using `<a>` tag, it used to redirect to whatever you value you given in `href`. So before executing your script you are suppose to prevent default behavior of you `<a>` tag.

Use `event.preventDefault()` in your `onclick` script. This prevent default redirection of your `<a>` tag.

Find the [fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/rajsnd08/oqk3hknp/) for your reference.

Hope it helps.